# How to summon an armorstand with a block that has properties tags

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can't get this to work: `{SpawnPotentials:[{Properties:{NBT tag}}]}`

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,NoGravity:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"stone_stairs",SpawnPotentials:[{Properties:{half:top}}],Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],DisabledSlots:1052688}
```

I tried it with the `tag:{}` aswell but didnt get it to work

I want to be able to summon an armorstand with a stair with `slab:top` and no I can't use the rotation of the armorstandhead

Don't know if its possible but I solved it by making a model for it instead

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `SpawnPotentials` is not a tag of items, only of spawners. I also don't know what `Properties` does there. You can't just invent any syntax you like, you have to use the one that the game understands. The Minecraft wiki documents all possibilities.
2. Stair items don't have block states, because they aren't blocks.

Comment: This was taken right from the minecraft wiki and It is not an "invented" syntax

This is for a summon falling sand command which I've used for a door {BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:smooth_red_sandstone_stairs",Properties:{facing:"west"}},Time:1}

The properties tag is used for the orientation of blocks so you're clearly in the wrong here

Comment: Falling BLOCKS use data of blocks, ArmorITEMS uses data of items. No, you can not use data of blocks in items.

Comment: Does this mean there is no way of making it possible?

Comment: Not like that at least. I don't know what you want to do, but falling blocks could be what you want.